# Find the "1"s in a list

Tags: python

I need to find a book's page count. The pages have 689 1's in it. So it goes 1,2,3,..11,12,.. in order to find the page count, I need to count the 1's. I thought:

```
book = []
page = 0

while True:
    page += 1
    book.append(page)
    if book.count(1) == 689: 
        print("The book is {} pages".format(page))
        break
```

but .count(1) does not include 11,21,111 etc. What can I use instead of .count()?

Comment: To count the number of digits equal to 1 in a single page number, you can convert it to a string and then count the characters that are `"1"`, i.e. `str(page).count("1")`.

Comment: This is completely unclear. Are you trying to ask how many page numbers end with the digit 1? `if str(number).endswith('1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to count the number of pages, you could try to just keep track of a counter variable accumlatively instead of using `count` on the whole `book` array.

```
# book = []
page = 0
count = 0

while True:
    page += 1
#   book.append(page)
    count += str(page).count('1')
    if count == 689: 
        print("The book is {} pages".format(page))
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
book = []
page = 0
sum_of_ones = 0
while True:
    page += 1
    book.append(page)
    sum_of_ones += str(book[-1]).count("1")
    if sum_of_ones == 689:
        print(f"this book has {page} pages.")
        break

#output
1234 pages
```

I believe this is an efficient way.

It keeps counting the newly added page to the book and increases the sum if possible then rechecks if it is `==689` . It breaks when the number is met.

Only issue is that it will keep iterating if `689` is not met